# How to index a MySQL table when both >= and <= is used?

Tags: mysql

Let's say you have a query like,

```
select ID, REGION, START, END from COORD_SYSTEM 
where REGION=? and TYPE=? and START >= ? and END <= ?;
```

And let's say this table has around 50,000 rows. The REGION column has 500 distinct values and the TYPE column has 50 distinct values. The ID column is the primary key.

What would be the best way to index the table? I'm not quite sure if one could achieve a *covering index* due to the >= and <= signs. Here are a few options:

1. create index on COORD_SYSTEM (REGION, TYPE)
2. create index on COORD_SYSTEM (REGION, TYPE, START)
3. create index on COORD_SYSTEM (REGION, TYPE, START, END)

**Update - Here's the explain statement:**

```
          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: COORD_SYSTEM
         type: range
possible_keys: indx_A
          key: indx_A
      key_len: 50
          ref: NULL
         rows: 590
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'd say 3 should be better for that, have you tried it on some test data with large number of rows?

Comment: With option 3 it should be able to run on the index only. Also option 2 and 3 should have the same amount of scanned rows. Can you post the EXPLAIN's ?

Comment: have you tried `create index on COORD_SYSTEM (REGION, TYPE, START, END desc)`??

Comment: The `select_type` information is not enough, please tell us about the values in the `Extra` column too (last column)

Comment: @RandomSeed sure I added the explain statement.

Comment: You previously gave surprising information about Option #2 involving less rows than Option #3. Could you please post the execution plan of these two situations, or at least tell us what configuration your last edit describes?

Comment: Actually I changed the order of the indexes - before it had been (REGION, START, END, TYPE).... and I changed it to (REGION, TYPE, START, END). This produced the most dramatic improvement... the # rows examined shrunk by 75%.

Comment: Yes, the order of the columns in an index definition is important too. The index can only be used by checking the `WHERE` conditions in the order the columns appear in the index. It is likely that, after your last change, most records have already been filtered out after applying the conditions on `region` and `type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that you can't use a covering index with range operators. The challenge (for non-covering indexes) is that the optimizer might think that a full scan might result in fewer page reads if your range is large, and the index won't be used for some of your queries. Similarly, for some parameter values, the optimizer may choose to do a full scan if the covering index isn't much better than a scan for some sets of parameters.

So, given the description in the question it's not actually possible to give the optimal solution for all cases.

What I tend to do with things like that is:

- Create a copy of the database
- Guess which index *might* do the job, and create that index.
- `EXPLAIN` several queries with different sized ranges (more ranges need more I/O to get back to the table data if you haven't covered the query, so you should try for common range sizes and outliers)
- Drop the index and try another, perhaps with a different covering index with the columns in a different order

You might even choose to create two or more covering indexes with the fields in different orders, assuming you run this query considerably more times than corresponding `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s, and that the size of the index isn't a factor for disk space usage.

Comment: Thanks! The last tip about re-ordering the index fields was very helfpul: it reduced the number of rows examined drastically.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of an index as a way of pre-sorting rows by the values in the indexed columns. An index can be used for a comparison with `>=` and `<=` in the same way as with `=`.

Your option 3 is *probably* the best index, in the sense that all `WHERE` conditions could be checked just by looking at the index. Whether it *actually is* the best index depends on your data set, because, for example, if most of your records have a very large value for `end`, all records would meet the condition `WHERE end <= ?` and an index would be of little use on this field (and the optimiser could decide not to use the index for this field because it would induce an overhead with no "return on investment")

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `BETWEEN` command, you won't need a START and END for this.. you can get between with only 1 table row.

```
SELECT ID, REGION, START, END from COORD_SYSTEM WHERE REGION=? and TYPE=? BETWEEN 100 and 200;
```

Comment: No... You can see from the query that START and END are two separate columns in the table, and I am passed two separate arguments to compare with.