# MySQL not using multiple column index for some queries

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, myisam

I have a table with several million records on MySQL in an MyISAM table. Very simplified, it's like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `text` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `number` (`number`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `text_number` (`text`,`number`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It's populated with this data:

```
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('abcd', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('abcd', '2');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('abcd', '3');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('abcd', '4');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('bbbb', '1');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('bbbb', '2');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('bbbb', '3');
```

When I run the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE (`text` = 'bbbb' AND `number` = 2)
```

It returns 'number' as the key to use. But the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE (`text` = 'bbbb' AND `number` = 1)
```

Returns 'text_number' as key to use, which would make more sense to me as this combined key matches exactly with the 2 columns in the WHERE. On these amount of records the performance isn't an issue, but on several million records the query which uses the 'text' index takes 4 seconds, and the one that uses 'text_number' index is finished in several milliseconds.

Is there a logical explaination for this? How can I change the index that MySQL uses the index? I know I can use USE INDEX but I want MySQL to be able to find the best plan to execute the query. This is on MySQL 5.1 and 5.5, same results.

Comment: SQL Fiddle shows the same index being used for both (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8b239/2).

Comment: I'm voting to move this to dba.stackexchange, this is bizarre and I think it needs someone who knows a vast amount about MyISAM index selection. In [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65880/3) the data is perfectly symmetrical (i.e. the same 4 numbers for each text), when searching for 6 of the combinations it uses the text_number index, when searching for `2` it uses `number`, I have no idea why. I thought it might be due to thresholds at which statistics get updated, but I moved the creation of the indexes to after the data was inserted to avoid this.

Comment: In addition, the insert order does not make any difference (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ba8d/1), the order in the index does not make any difference (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ec901/1), and it appears to always happen on the second lowest number, rather than specifically on the number 2, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8753/2, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3f572/2. However, you would expect it to use the `number` index on the second highest number when the index is reversed, but it doesn't it is still on the second lowest. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30020/1. A complete mystery to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect some of the queries to be game changer for the performance it is good idea to use you own indexes, like:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test` USE INDEX (number) WHERE (`text` = 'bbbb' AND `number` = 1);
or
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test` USE INDEX (text_number) WHERE (`text` = 'bbbb' AND `number` = 1);
```

Generally, you can relay on the built-in query optimizer for most of the queries, but for the crucial or problematic ones it is good idea to look closer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that could improve your performance:

1. `ANALYZE TABLE` to update your optimizer's index statistics so it knows the current key distribution. You can [control the optimizer's statistics generation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-other-changes-statistics-estimation.html) in a number of ways.
2. Create a second covering index with the fields reversed. In the real world, this involves figuring out the optimal one or two covering indexes for a set of three or four columns, and that's something you arrive at through benchmarking and `EXPLAIN` analysis. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182140/how-to-index-a-mysql-table-when-both-and-is-used/18182294#18182294) for some advice on doing that.

Comment: I tried to ANALYZE the table, but it wouldn't matter. Can give the second option a try though!